# Add `mchem` to MathJax Extensions?

Tags: feature-request, bug, mathjax

I tried using `\ce{}` earlier in an answer but it didn't work!

Although [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax) shows that Astronomy has MathJax extensions, why doesn't it work?

After some discussion on meta, I think maybe we can add the `mhchem` extension? Not sure. Yes it does slow down page loading, but some equations require me to use non-italicized characters, which `mhchem` provides.

Comment: Is mhchem standard in a version of Mathjax for additional requiring explicit dev support for all versions ?

Answer (score 6):

Supplemental answer only:

See my question in Space SE meta [Should we start using the normal MathJax chemistry notation for chemicals? e.g. \require{mhchem}\ce{H_2O} for H₂O](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2918/12102)

Each site decides if they want every single page to *preload* the chemistry stuff or not. For those that don't currently but still have MathJax (like Astronomy SE and Space SE for example), you simply have to prepend `\require{mhchem}` to your first instance of `\ce{}` to trigger loading of the chemistry stuff on the page.

I won't answer your question about turning on the chemistry stuff for the whole site automatically, I can imagine arguments both ways.